# Images are not proxied correctly when using NodeJS + Request module

Tags: node.js, proxy, node-request

I have a proxy that works well (as far as I can tell) UNTIL I attempt to proxy images (or perhaps any binary data?). By my estimations, the below code *should* work, but it does not. I'm sure I"m doing something obviously dumb, but I've been digging through forums and apis and I have yet to hit upon the correct approach.

The 'core' of my proxy looks something like the following.

```
  function(req, res) {
    ...

    options = {
      url: 'a url',
      headers: {
        'Authorization': auth
      }
    };

    request(options,
      function(e, r, b){
        var encoding = (r.headers['content-type'].indexOf('image') === -1) ? 'utf8' : 'binary';

        res.writeHead(200, {
          'Content-Length': r.headers['content-length'],
          'Content-Type': r.headers['content-type']
        });

        if (encoding === 'binary') {
          b = new Buffer(b);
        }

        res.end(b, encoding);
      });
    }
```

What am I missing here?

Thanks in advance for any and all help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My problem was not with the response (as I though originally), but rather the fact that the request module was encoding it's response body to unicode by default, when disabled (`encoding: null`), the response body is converted to a buffer which is easily consumed by the response.

```
    options = {
      url: url,
      encoding: null,
      headers: {
        'Authorization': auth
      }
    };

    request(options,
      function(e, r, b){
        var encoding = (r.headers['content-type'].indexOf('image') === -1) ? 'utf8' : 'binary';
        res.end(b, encoding);
      });
```